# Virtualization software for static server running on Linux

Tags: linux, virtualization, docker

I am looking for software that I can run on my personal Linux Server that encapsulate a OS for fast on/off functionality

I have been experimenting for the last year and a half with docker and have been running about 2-8 containers continuously since then.

From my experience Docker is more for continues delivery/deployment than continuously running containers that I will just be stopping and starting when I want to. It just feels like a hassle to work with docker when I want to change my setup.

For example I have not been able to have a nginx/haproxy on the host machine which links to containers, I had to have a docker-compose file with a nginx container which couples everything together and that is something that I don't want

My requirements for this software is

- Needs to be able to have a static IP address on containers for my proxy which I will be running on the Host system
- Starting and stopping containers should be easy.
- Should be isolated from the host OS but still able to share disk volumes
- Should be able to have up to 10 running servers or more
- Open-source / free
- I am currently unable to get physical access to the machine so compatibility with the current machine is a must

My current server is running on Ubuntu server 14.04

I have been looking around for software like this but there is so much available I thought it would be best to ask the experts :)

Answer (score 1):

Look into Linux containers - LXC.

https://linuxcontainers.org

This will provide you isolation, network namespaces, quick boot, encapsulation and everything else you've requested.